# long compilation time of the simplest example of cpp-netlib

Tags: c++, cpp-netlib

I'm using visual studio 2015 c++ compiler, boost 1.59 and cpp-netlib 0.11.2. I'm compiling with precompiled header. The compilation time of the simplest example of cpp-netlib takes more than 2.5 min. Is this normal? Can i speed it up?

Comment: Hmya, the term "library" is getting to be pretty meaningless these days.  It is just a big blob of header files with super-expensive template hacking.  If you don't take advantage of your compiler's precompiled headers feature then you pay dearly.

Comment: Seems like answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34099751/23118).